# Text vertical alignment in TwwDBGrid

Tags: delphi

I noticed that text is not centralize vertically in `TwwDBGrid` and there is no property to do that. Is it any way to centralize text vertically in rows? I see there is a option to do that for `TStringGrid`, but no for `TwwDBGrid`.

Comment: I've never used `TwwDBGrid` but I think there should be a `OnDrawCell` event where you can set text align (see `SetTextAlign` function)

Comment: I have there OnDrawDataCell so it should be similar. How can I set text vertical alignment in OnDrawCell event?

Comment: Could you please show us parameters of `OnDrawDataCell `

Comment: Of course! It looks like this: GridDrawDataCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I figured out solution how to do text vertical alignment for `TwwDBGrid`.
On `DataDrawCellEvent` I added code like below:

```
procedure TfrmTest.fraTestwwGridDrawDataCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; Field: TField; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  MyRect: TRect;
begin
   fraTest.wwGrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect); // clear area
   MyRect := Rect;

   DrawText(fraTest.wwGrid.Canvas.Handle, PChar(Field.AsString),
      Length(Field.AsString), MyRect, DT_VCENTER or DT_SINGLELINE or DT_NOPREFIX); // draw single line vertically centered
```